# How to iterate through an array whose variable name depends on a different variable

Tags: javascript, arrays

I tried Google this, but it's hard to explain what I am trying to do.

I am returned with a string `var returnedString = model one`.

Suppose I have a bunch of arrays called

```
var model_one   = ['a', 'b', 'c']
var model_two   = ['d', 'e', 'f']
var model_three = ['f', 'g', 'h']
```

This is what I have done

```
var selectedArrayName = returnedString.replace(" ", "_") //model_one
```

And this is what I want to do...

```
for (i in array with name selectedArrayName) {
    print selectedArrayName's array index. 
}
```

Comment: Don't use three variables. Use an object.

Comment: @Bergi, wait a minute... I feel like I tried doing this but something stopped me. Now I can't think of why.

Comment: Oh, and [don't use `for…in` enumerations on arrays!](https://stackoverflow.com/q/500504/1048572)

Comment: @Bergi I was just speaking in psudo code, hahaha Don't worry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to approach this would be to **create a dictionary of models**, which can be accessed via bracket notation `[]`:

```js
var models = {
  model_one: ['a', 'b', 'c'],
  model_two: ['d', 'e', 'f'],
  model_three: ['f', 'g', 'h']
};
var modelName = 'model_one';

for(var index in models[modelName]) {
  var content = models[modelName][index];
  console.log(index, content);
}
```

Comment: I was just going to comment this! Thank you for the love and supper Timo!

Answer (score 1):

If you are on the client side and not in a function, you could access it using

```
for (var i in window[selectedArrayName]) {
    // print selectedArrayName's array index. 
}
```

The better way, as suggested in the comment is to do something like

```
var models = {
    model_one: ['a', 'b', 'c'],
    model_two: ['d', 'e', 'f'],
    model_three: ['f', 'g', 'h']
};

for(var i in models[selectedArrayName]) {
    // print selectedArrayName's array index. 
}
```